# MySQL user-defined variables in Node.js mysql module

Tags: mysql, node.js

I was wondering whether MySQL user-defined variables will work using Node.js mysql module. The example below highlight exactly what I want to achieve using a transaction:

```
connection.beginTransaction(err => {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET = ?', {id: 12, username: 'name'}, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return connection.rollback(function() {
                throw error;
            });
        }

        connection.query('SELECT @user_id:=userID FROM user WHERE username = ?', ['name'], (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return connection.rollback(function() {
                    throw error;
                });
            }

            connection.query('INSERT INTO authentication SET `userID` = @user_id, ?', {password: 'userpassword'}, (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return connection.rollback(function() {
                        throw error;
                    });
                }

                connection.commit(err => {
                    if (err) {
                        return connection.rollback(function() {
                            throw err;
                        });
                    }

                    console.log('success!');
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You might be wondering, why not use the result of the second query in the third query. The transaction function is wrapped inside a utility function that accepts queries as an argument to be executed using transaction.

If the above code sample doesn't work, please is there a concise way to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: If you have the code why don't you try it yourself and see?

Comment: @Shadow That is a good point, but I don't have the luxury to test code at the moment. I was wondering whether this will work for me to decide how I will structure my database.

Comment: Testing code is not a luxury. It is a necessity. We definitely cannot test your code because we miss a lot of context and database structure. Furthermore, I fail to see how the correctness of the above code has any influence on the database structure.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for your effort. Am setting up the environment to run the code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running the code sample it failed not because of MySQL variable in the second query. This code sample is what works for me:

```
connection.beginTransaction(err => {
    if (err) { throw err; }

    connection.query('INSERT INTO user (id, username) VALUES(?, ?)', [12, 'name'], (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return connection.rollback(function() {
               throw error;
            });
        }

        connection.query('SELECT @user_id:=userID FROM user WHERE username = ?', ['name'], (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                return connection.rollback(function() {
                    throw error;
                });
            }

            connection.query('INSERT INTO authentication (id, password) VALUES (@user_id, ?), ['userpassword'], (err, results) => {
                if (err) {
                    return connection.rollback(function() {
                        throw error;
                    });
                }

                connection.commit(err => {
                    if (err) {
                        return connection.rollback(function() {
                            throw err;
                        });
                    }

                    console.log('success!');
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```